# How to sort in desc order using primitive type?

Tags: java

### **My situation**

I have a data structure of primitive type of `int[][] numbers`. **I want to sort in desc order**;

### **Reverse Array**

Yes, I did it by converting my array as list like this: `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array))`
But what's the purpose? I have reversed it,OK, now I am sorting it by doing this: `Arrays.sort(array[i])`

And then...PUFF MAGIC. I have only ASC order, not DESC.

Any other approach?

THANKS!

After doing this my result is: ( it is obvious the result isn't correct)

```
111112223333555555566788899
888
2334455556777
33
113359
11222344455566667777788889
2555679
12
344445566788
156779
```

Should be:

```
111112223333555555566788899
888
**77765555443322**
--- and so on..
```

### **EDITED:**

I tried with comparator, it seems that I am doing something wrong by using it in this situation. Because normally it works for me pretty well. But now..

```
  Arrays.sort(arrInt[i],new Comparator<Integer>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                    return o2.compareTo(o1);
                }

            });
        }
```

Then I am using Wrapper class of int , comparator suits for me.

Comment: so each `int[]` represents the digits of a number? why not use `BigInteger[]` instead of `int[][]`?

Comment: As I understand , each array[i] respresents my array[i][] line

Comment: Because I want to make some actions with these numbers. So I need it hold separated with each other.

Comment: Comment on first reversing, then sorting... If you want to reverse result of sort, reverse *after* sorting... :-)

Comment: It doesn't make sense at all. I tried it. I will post my code in edit scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- Use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) to call `ArrayUtils.reverse(array)` after you've sorted.
- Use `System.arraycopy` to reverse copy into a new array.
- Convert your array to an `Integer[]` and implement a custom `Comparator` Then `Arrays.sort(array, new ReverseIntegerComparator())`

  ```
  public class ReverseIntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

      @Override
      public int compare(Integer first, Integer second) {
          return second.compareTo(first);
      }
  }
  ```

Also, make sure you want an `int[][]`. Your question implies you want just `int[]`. But either way, once you get to the `int[]`, you can use any of these options and probably many others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the task require implementation of a sorting algorithm for your own? ;-)
If you still want to use the `Arrays` class you can implement `sort` with the `Comparator`:

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

And provide proper comparator.

Alternatively try with

```
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Maybe it will help you.

Comment: The task did not require anything, it is only for practice purposes. I did it with comparator and it seems that it doesn't work. I will edit my post with that code.

Comment: It would work IF I have an Integer. It's a pity, but I have int. In this cases it makes sense;

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will sort the array at position i, but will not sort the big array containing all the arrays. To do this, first sort each integer array (or just find its maximum value if you don't actually need to sort it), then do

```
Arrays.sort(arrInt,new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
            return o2[0].compareTo(o1[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to sort only at position, because then my index is even number I sort my numbers in asc order, and vice versa;

Comment: You should update your question to make this intent clear, because it's not. Also, check your English; that took a bit of thought to figure out what you meant.